# Gvim still showing lines changed

Tags: windows-10, gvim

I just installed gvim 7.4 on a new windows 10 machine. Consider the following text

[image]

When I hover over "bar" and press `cw` to change word, I see the following

[image]

Note that the word "bar" hasn't been removed, it still shows and a $ sign seems to indicate end of what would be deleted. If I press `C` to change to rest of the line I see the following.

[image]

I am pretty sure that in my previous versions/installs of gvim whenever I tried to change anything, the text that was going to be modified was actually removed straight away, not marked with a $ sign until the removal mark.

I am guessing there is some option that I need to enable/disable somewhere?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are describing sounds like the original vi (as opposed to Vim).  Did you actually install version 4.7, or was that a typo? The newest version is 7.4.

If you did install 4.7, then that may explain it.  I'm not quite sure how that old of a version behaves.

If you are running 7.4, then you may be running in compatible mode which makes it behave like the old vi.  You can run `:set compatible?` inside vim to see what mode you are running in.  If it says `compatible` in the bottom, then you are running in the mode that makes it behave as you've described.  You can run `:set nocompatible` to turn this off.  Add that to your `_vimrc` file to make it happen each time you start vim.

Comment: Sorry.  It was 7.4. I updated the question accordingly. Typing `:set compatible?` returns `nocompatible`. But I tried the `:set nocompatible` anyway and it now works properly. Strange. I will add it to the _vimrc. Thanks heaps.